# Laravel 5.8 use an array in a validation rule

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "text/csv"
  1 => "text/plain"
]
```

I want to use this array in my validation rule like this:

```
return [
    'file' => 'mimetypes:' . $array,
];
```

But this is not working, do I need to encode it to a string or something?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimetypes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) the array. It should look like this:

```
return [
    'file' => 'mimetypes:' . implode(',', $array),
];
```

Imploding will take all of the values of the array and glue them together using the first argument, in this case `,`, giving you a string of values from the array separated by the `,` character.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
return [
    'file' => 'mimetypes:' . implode(',', $array)
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this kind of Simple code :

```
 $file_rules = ["text/csv","text/plain"];

    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'city'      =>  'required',
        'profile_image' => 'mimes:$file_rules' // otherwise  'mimes:'.implode(',', $file_rules)
    ];
    $messages = [
        'username'    => 'The :attribute shoud be Required.',
        'city'    => 'The :attribute should be required.',
        'profile_image' => 'The :attribute should be Required.',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
```

it's working try this one.....